# Unity FirebaseDatabase, как запустить следующую сцену после возвращения данных.

Tags: android, unity3d, firebase-database

Нужна помощь, нужно открыть следующую сену после возвращения данных из Firebase.
Но появляется ошибка, что я не в основном потоке, может кто то сталкивался.

```
public class StartScript : MonoBehaviour {

void Start () {


    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("my_url");
   FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
  .GetReference("/")
  .GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
      if (task.IsFaulted)
      {
          // Handle the error...
      }
      else if (task.IsCompleted)
      {
          DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
          // Do something with snapshot...
          if (snapshot.Value.Equals("none")) {
              SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
          }
      }
  });


}


void Update () {

}
```

}

Ошибка:

**LoadSceneAsyncNameIndexInternal can only be called from the main thread.
Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene.
Don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers, instead move initialization code to the Awake or Start function.
UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager:LoadScene(Int32)
StartScript:m__0(Task`1) (at Assets/Scripts/StartScript.cs:31)
System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback:PerformWaitCallback()
**

Comment: Вы вызываете код Unity не из главного потока, о чем вам и говорит ошибка. Исправить ее никак нельзя - в Unity запрещено вызывать практически весь код Unity api из других потоков.

Comment: Это понятно, а что можно сделать что бы после получения данных, я смог запустить другую сцену?

Comment: Можно ли дождаться выполнения таска, вес вечер ищу ответа, как то безуспешно.

Comment: К примеру, заведите bool переменную, значение true которое будет сигнализировать об окончании загрузки. В главном потоке каждый кадр проверяйте значение этой переменной.

Comment: Блин, спасибо это сработало, вы очень помогли.

Answer (score 0):

Вот что вышло.

```
public class StartScript : MonoBehaviour {
bool check = false;
string link = "";
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("myurl");
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
    .GetReference("/")
    .GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
        if (task.IsFaulted){

        }
        else if (task.IsCompleted)
        {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;

            link = snapshot.Value.ToString();
            }
        check = true;

    });
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (check == true) {
        if (link.Equals("none")) {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene1");
        }

    }
}
```

}